# Django: how do I specify on which apps and migrations test case depends?

Tags: django, django-testing, django-apps, django-tests

I want to speed up my tests by running only necessary migrations to build database. Currently, Django runs all of them.

I know how to specify dependencies among migrations and actively use it. I watch for dependencies, most of my tests don't depend even on Django. I want some dividends for that.

Is there any way to specify particular apps or migrations on which test depends?

I found [`available_apps`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.available_apps) property of `TransactionTestCase`, which is marked as private API, but it doesn't work for me. Even if I run single test class or test method.

Comment: You might find the [`--keepdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test--keepdb) option useful, to prevent Django from recreating the database and running the migrations each time you run the tests.

Comment: @Alasdair Yes, I know this option but it's still not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: But what the use? if you don't want to use --keepdb you will spend a lot of time and effort to save a few seconds.

Comment: I don't want to depend on anything else. Migrations from other apps written by other developers may fail. I may use in-memory SQLite db. There may be a lot of reasons. Why is it effort? `python manage.py migrate myapp` works perfectly and install only specific dependencies. I expect same for tests.

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov I am currently facing the same issue. Have you figured out how to apply migrations only for the specific app during the test?